# How do i filter in TCL script API

Tags: bash, api, tcl

I need to filter the response from getWater and getSoda. The problem I have is when I try to get response in API I get both querys. So  in cli lets say i put CLI:getWater the response it gives for both water and soda i need to  distinguish between the two  if you look at the end line  it gives you 1 for Water and 0 for Soda. I'm trying to make filter in TCL file so if i put getWater it only pulls out the query with whatever ends with 1 and vice versa.
`cli% getWater {2 Fiji - {} 1 {} b873-367ef9944d48 **1**} {3 Coke - {} 1 {} 9d39-56ad9be6ee9f **0**} {6 Dasani - {} 1 {} 9d39-56ad9be6ee9f **1**} {9 Fanta - {} 1 {} 9d39-56ad9be6ee9f **0**}`

im having hard time coding it because in not familiar with TCL
but so far to get query i got this.

```
proc API::get {args} {
    set argc [llength $args]
    
    if {$argc == 1} {
        # get all sets based on set type
        set objtype [lindex $args 0]
        catcher getset_int $objtype {} {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have some command (that I'll call `getListOfRecords` for the sake of argument) and you want to filter the returned list by the value of the 8th element (index 7; TCL uses zero-based indexing) of each record? You can do that with either `lmap`+`lindex` or with `lsearch` (with the right options).

```
proc getRecordsOfType {typeCode} {
    lmap r [getListOfRecords] {
        if {[lindex $r 7] eq $typeCode} {set r} else continue
    }
}
```

```
proc getRecordsOfType {typeCode} {
    lsearch -all -inline -exact -index 7 [getListOfRecords] $typeCode
}
```

Using `lsearch` is *probably* faster, but the other approach is far more flexible. (Measure instead of guessing if it matters to you.)

`getWater` is just `getRecordsOfType 1`.